# File not open for reading

Tags: python, file, url-rewriting

```
def save_list(todolist, filename):
    """ writes the todo list to the filename in correct format

    save_list(todolist, filename) -> list
    """

    fd = open(filename, 'w') #creates file
    for line in fd:
        date = as_date_string(line[0]) #to put into correct format
        chore = line[1] # assigns chore from touple value
        fd.writelines(text)
        fd.close()
    print result
```

when i try to run this function I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    save_list(load_list('todo.txt'), 'todo.txt')
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\CSSE1001\Assignment\assign1.py", line 58, in save_list
    for line in fd:
IOError: File not open for reading
```

The function is supposed to load a list and write the list to a file
for eg
`save_list(load_list('todo.txt'), 'todo.txt')`
should rewrite the file with the same information

Answer (score 2):

As the error clearly says, the file is not open for reading. You need to open it for read/write:

```
fd = open(filename, 'r+')
```

I suggest you to check out how to [read and write files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in python.

**Edit**:

Also, as Dannnno pointed out, you're closing your file inside de loop. You need to move `fd.close()` out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code. You close your file inside of your for loop.  You also have it write only, you want read/write

```
fd = open(filename, 'r+') #creates file
for line in fd:
    date = as_date_string(line[0]) #to put into correct format
    chore = line[1] # assigns chore from touple value
    fd.writelines(text)
fd.close()
```

You also don't define `text` anywhere but I don't know what it is supposed to be so I can't help you there